# XNA 4.0 keeping fonts/sprites without the use of a content project

Tags: xna, c#, xna-4.0

*Note: The actual title of my question does not really reflect my problem but is actually one of the possible solutions to my problem. I couldn't find a proper way to express my question so feel free to propose a different title.*

So I've recently moved to XNA 4.0 and I'm new to this whole *content project* idea.
I made a simple component based "engine" as a game library that I reuse over all my projects.

I implemented some basic debugging tools like a frame rate counter which used a `SpriteFont`, which was stored within the actual engine library.

Now that all the content was moved out of the library with XNA 4.0, I don't know where to put the `SpriteFont` and all other content used by the engine.

**I'd rather avoid having to include both the content project and the engine library every time I start a new program, but is this my only option?**

**Or is there a way to include content within a library without resorting to content projects?**

Comment: To be honest, I believe that you shouldn't have your engine anywhere near your game project. You should keep both seperate, making your engine a class library that is referenced by your game engine. At _worst_ you should add your game library as a reference, never copy the entire source & content into each game.

Comment: Oh that's what it is. I just add the project to my solution and reference it. I just wanted to know if I had to add a content project in the process too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think adding the solution to each new project is the best and easiest way to accomplish what you want.

**You can open two projects up at once, and drag the solution from one to another, it takes seconds, and it stays very organized.**

Comment: Alright, I guess it's not a big problem after all... I just panicked when I noticed my debug content couldn't load anymore and I was a little bit lost. Thank you for your answer (and the open two projects trick, didn't know about that).